# Calling Fragment interface method in parent Activity onBackPressed method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity that extends AppCompatActivity. And also in this Activity I have a ViewPager that filled like so:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "Tab1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "Tab2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3(), "Tab3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

In my Tab Fragment I have a RecyclerView with multiple selection implemented with some library.
I want to implement closing of selection mode by pressing hardware back button.

I have this function in my Fragment for this:

```
public void closeSelectMode() {
        if(mMultiSelector.isSelectable())
            setSelection(mMultiSelector);
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

But I don't know how to put this function in parent Activity onBackPressed().

Also I trying to implement this using Fragment interface but I don't know how to put implementation of interface function in onBackPressed function to parent Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override onBackPressed of your Activity in this way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_name);
    if (fragment instanceof YourFragment) {
        YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) fragment;
        yourFragment.closeSelectMode();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! It works cool! But instead of
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_name); I use fragment = adapter.getItem(0);